# Correctness of Scikit-learn for MLR?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression

Hi I have correctness issues with scikit-learn package for mlr (linear_model.LinearRegression). In all cases, the same data is used and built without intercept

Python code:

```
data = np.loadtxt(fname=file, delimiter='\t')
X = data[:, 1:]
Y = data[:, 1]
mlr = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
mlr.fit(X,Y)
print(mlr.coef_)

1.00000000e+00  6.20460347e-17 -1.82373860e-17  3.35782591e-19
7.92128777e-17 -1.04990677e-17 -1.15961796e-16  1.33629653e-15
```

R:

```
Y = data[,1]
X = data[,-1]
X = as.matrix(X)
m1 = lm(Y~X-1)
m1$coefficients

 0.0546782907  0.0159731763  0.1312037785 -0.0507591565  0.1036469860 

 0.0050217163 -0.1006476385  0.0248998498  0.0081473528 -0.0111405854
```

C# (using accord.net, fairly involved procedure posting results only):

```
 0.0546782906719276*x0 + 0.0159731763215885*x1 + 0.13120377853918*x2 + -0.0507591564748648*x3 + 0.103646986044143*x4 + 0.00502171630071436*x5
```

Any reason why?

tldr; used `scikit-learn`, `R`, `C#` `accord.net` to compare mlr coefficients, get bs results from sklearn while accord.net & r give similar results

Comment: Could you generate some reproducible example?

Comment: Would you please add some fit statistics such as RMSE and R-squared to the post? This allows for additional comparative analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out why (it my own dummy mistake)

`Y = data[:, 1]` wrong!!

change to:

`Y = data[:, 0]`

Now i get this (which is correct):

```
5.46782907e-02  1.59731763e-02  1.31203779e-01 -5.07591565e-02
  1.03646986e-01  5.02171630e-03 -1.00647639e-01  2.48998498e-02
```